# My 3g internet is not working anymore

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

My 3g usb key used to work like a charm, and now, despite it is recognized and connected (listed under "mobile connexion" in network manager) i can't reach internet. I already reinstalled network manager without success
  Needless to say the usb key is working well (under Windows)

What shall I do ?

i'm running ubuntu 16.04.2

```
#lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:140c Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E180v
```

here is the syslog when I activate the connexion :

```
Jul 29 17:35:15 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349715.7853] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: starting connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1' (f79c564b-39fb-48d6-a4a9-90390fa2681a)
Jul 29 17:35:15 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349715.7858] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 29 17:35:15 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349715.7862] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 29 17:35:15 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349715.7878] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> need-auth (reason 'none') [40 60 0]
Jul 29 17:35:15 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349715.9185] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jul 29 17:35:15 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect started...
Jul 29 17:35:15 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
Jul 29 17:35:15 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (5/8): Register
Jul 29 17:35:15 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (6/8): Bearer
Jul 29 17:35:15 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (7/8): Connect
Jul 29 17:35:15 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (registered -> connecting)
Jul 29 17:35:17 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connecting -> connected)
Jul 29 17:35:17 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (8/8): All done
Jul 29 17:35:17 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349717.1068] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 29 17:35:17 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349717.1075] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul 29 17:35:17 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349717.1081] dhcp4 (wwan0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 15 seconds)
Jul 29 17:35:17 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349717.1109] dhcp4 (wwan0): dhclient started with pid 23513
Jul 29 17:35:17 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349717.1111] (cdc-wdm0): IPv6 configuration disabled
Jul 29 17:35:17 localhost dhclient[23513]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.2.5.162 on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x44d51c77)
Jul 29 17:35:24 localhost dhclient[23513]: message repeated 2 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 10.2.5.162 on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x44d51c77)]
Jul 29 17:35:31 localhost dhclient[23513]: DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xa359f62a)
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <warn>  [1501349732.7618] dhcp4 (wwan0): request timed out
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.7618] dhcp4 (wwan0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.7783] dhcp4 (wwan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 23513
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.7783] dhcp4 (wwan0): state changed timeout -> done
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.7789] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.7794] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <warn>  [1501349732.7810] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: failed for connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1'
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.7821] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.7865] policy: auto-activating connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1'
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.7886] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: starting connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1' (f79c564b-39fb-48d6-a4a9-90390fa2681a)
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connected -> disconnecting)
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (disconnecting -> registered)
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.8016] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.8017] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.8022] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> need-auth (reason 'none') [40 60 0]
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349732.9236] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect started...
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (5/8): Register
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (6/8): Bearer
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (7/8): Connect
Jul 29 17:35:32 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (registered -> connecting)
Jul 29 17:35:34 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connecting -> connected)
Jul 29 17:35:34 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (8/8): All done
Jul 29 17:35:34 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349734.2902] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 29 17:35:34 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349734.2908] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul 29 17:35:34 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349734.2913] dhcp4 (wwan0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 15 seconds)
Jul 29 17:35:34 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349734.2937] dhcp4 (wwan0): dhclient started with pid 23914
Jul 29 17:35:34 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349734.2938] (cdc-wdm0): IPv6 configuration disabled
Jul 29 17:35:34 localhost dhclient[23914]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.2.5.162 on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x2bec36fe)
Jul 29 17:35:40 localhost dhclient[23914]: message repeated 2 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 10.2.5.162 on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x2bec36fe)]
Jul 29 17:35:47 localhost dhclient[23914]: DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xfeab765f)
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <warn>  [1501349749.7739] dhcp4 (wwan0): request timed out
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.7740] dhcp4 (wwan0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.7904] dhcp4 (wwan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 23914
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.7904] dhcp4 (wwan0): state changed timeout -> done
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.7910] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.7914] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <warn>  [1501349749.7930] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: failed for connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1'
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.7940] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.7970] policy: auto-activating connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1'
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.7988] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: starting connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1' (f79c564b-39fb-48d6-a4a9-90390fa2681a)
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.7990] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.7992] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.8003] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> need-auth (reason 'none') [40 60 0]
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connected -> disconnecting)
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (disconnecting -> registered)
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.8145] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'modem-no-carrier') [60 120 25]
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.8147] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <warn>  [1501349749.8151] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: failed for connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1'
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.8161] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.8172] policy: auto-activating connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1'
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.8181] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: starting connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1' (f79c564b-39fb-48d6-a4a9-90390fa2681a)
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.8183] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.8184] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.8190] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> need-auth (reason 'none') [40 60 0]
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349749.9102] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect started...
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (5/8): Register
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (6/8): Bearer
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (7/8): Connect
Jul 29 17:35:49 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (registered -> connecting)
Jul 29 17:35:51 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connecting -> connected)
Jul 29 17:35:51 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Simple connect state (8/8): All done
Jul 29 17:35:51 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349751.3147] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 29 17:35:51 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349751.3152] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul 29 17:35:51 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349751.3157] dhcp4 (wwan0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 15 seconds)
Jul 29 17:35:51 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349751.3178] dhcp4 (wwan0): dhclient started with pid 24315
Jul 29 17:35:51 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349751.3179] (cdc-wdm0): IPv6 configuration disabled
Jul 29 17:35:51 localhost dhclient[24315]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.2.5.162 on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x5292186c)
Jul 29 17:36:00 localhost dhclient[24315]: message repeated 2 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 10.2.5.162 on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x5292186c)]
Jul 29 17:36:06 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <warn>  [1501349766.7695] dhcp4 (wwan0): request timed out
Jul 29 17:36:06 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349766.7696] dhcp4 (wwan0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jul 29 17:36:06 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349766.8020] dhcp4 (wwan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 24315
Jul 29 17:36:06 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349766.8021] dhcp4 (wwan0): state changed timeout -> done
Jul 29 17:36:06 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349766.8026] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jul 29 17:36:06 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349766.8028] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 29 17:36:06 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349766.8034] policy: disabling autoconnect for connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1'.
Jul 29 17:36:06 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <warn>  [1501349766.8042] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: failed for connection 'EXPRESSO connection 1'
Jul 29 17:36:06 localhost NetworkManager[1196]: <info>  [1501349766.8055] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 29 17:36:06 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connected -> disconnecting)
Jul 29 17:36:06 localhost ModemManager[1192]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (disconnecting -> registered)
```

Comment: Do you have any specific question(s)?

Comment: How shall I debug this and make it work again ? (forgot to mention : the key still works very well under windows)

Comment: That's not a question. Also, while you are editing your question, add any relevant info. to the question.

Comment: I have removed icinga2-bin, icinga2, telegraf, influxdb, grafana  and collectd-core + reboot, and now it works... the weird thing is that it used to work with all that software installed.